# Filtering data according to this month, this quarter and this year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working on filtering data from a database in PHP CI, I need to filter the data using dd menu that have fixed data ( This Month, This Quarter, This Year).
This is the code of the dropdown

```
                                    <select class="form-control lb-sort leaderboard-select" name="filter">
                                        <option >Sort</option>
                                        <option value="MONTH">This Month</option>
                                        <option value="QUARTER">This Quarter</option>
                                        <option value="YEAR">This Year</option>
                                        <option>All Time</option>
                                    </select>
```

and here the query code I am using to filter my data

```
    $filter = "";
            $filter_leaderboard="";
            if($_GET['filter']){
                $filter = $_GET['filter'];
            }
            if($filter === "MONTH"){
                $filter_leaderboard = "MONTH(updated_date) = MONTH(NOW())";
            }else if($filter === "QUARTER"){
                $filter_leaderboard = "QUARTER(updated_date) = QUARTER(NOW())";
      }else if($filter === "YEAR"){
                $filter_leaderboard = "YEAR(updated_date) = YEAR(NOW())";
            }

            $paramSelect = "*";
            $paramTable = " tbl_user  where ".$filter_leaderboard  ;
            $data['user'] = $this->Common_model->Common_join($paramSelect,$paramTable);
```

but filtering is not working ?

Can you help me to check where is my fault ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2942146/hashem-h-ramadan Can you please write the error?

Comment: There is no error, The queries when I am running on the SQL server it's giving me the results correctly but when I am writing the if condition to check which option I selected is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$filter_leaderboard=""` with `$filter_leaderboard=null` and try again.

Comment: this one is not working I tried before! Now If I am selecting the option This Month, it should run for me the query that has the condition of the month filter

Comment: Print the query and try manually then it will give you some error if there was any.

Comment: I tried to do print_r for the query it's giving me all the data in XML format. it's showing me the data.

Comment: `print_r` is used to display data in array format not xml...!

Comment: Thats what Imean, by mistake I typed the XML

Comment: Can you share what is the output of printing data?

Comment: ```Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [username] => user2@hotmail.com
            [name] =>user2            [created_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_date] => 2019-12-11 07:20:19
       
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [username] => user21@gmail.com
            [name] => USER21
            [created_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [updated_date] => 2020-03-03 15:48:16
            
        )

)```

Comment: This is not the data you want to apply filtration! Make sure you have the right data posted.